# Clipping multipatch with 2D polygons using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, clip, spatial-join, 3d-analyst, multipatch

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have a multipatch dataset and 2D polygon dataset.

Is there an automated way how I can clip one multipatch into separate features?

Using clip and split tools gives a topological error. I have a lot of features, which means that using editing tools won't work. Converting multipatches to a footprint can help clip the features, but can I recreate essentially the same multipatch, only split in some parts.

For example, I have polygons named 1147, 684 and 56 (shown in red, outlines in black). They are overlayed by one multipatch (shown in purple, outlines in red). I need to create 3 separate multipatches, which I can add attribute data with spatial join.

There are also multipatches that do not intersect with 2D polygons. In this example, that is not the case, but multipatch area can be bigger than 2D polygons, for which I have to use some sort of fusing.

[image]